# Express, webpack-dev-sever doesn't find React index

Tags: express, react-router, webpack-dev-server

i'm very new of Express and server side in general, for my small react messaging app i'm using Express for the backend(a json file) and webpack dev server for frontend.
If i start just the Webpack server, the app show correctly, probelems come when i try to make the two works together and i think the problem is the proxy configuration of webpack-dev-server.

Here is my express server, json-api-server.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var serveStatic = require('serve-static');
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');


module.exports = (PORT) => {

  const MESSAGES_FILE = path.join(__dirname, 'src/app/data/messages.json');
  const app = express();

  app.use(serveStatic(__dirname + '/build'));
  app.use(bodyParser.json());
  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

  // Additional middleware which will set headers that we need on each request.
  app.use(function(req, res, next) {
      // Set permissive CORS header - this allows this server to be used only as
      // an API server in conjunction with something like webpack-dev-server.
      res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

      // Disable caching so we'll always get the latest comments.
      res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');
      next();
  });

  app.get('/messages', function(req, res) {
    fs.readFile(MESSAGES_FILE, function(err, data) {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        process.exit(1);
      }
      res.json(JSON.parse(data));
    });
  });

  app.post('/messages', function(req, res) {
    fs.readFile(MESSAGES_FILE, function(err, data) {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        process.exit(1);
      }
      var messages = JSON.parse(data);

      var newMessage = {
        id: Date.now(),
        body: req.body.body,
        date: req.body.date,
        from: req.body.from,
        to: req.body.to
      };
      messages.push(newMessage);
      fs.writeFile(MESSAGES_FILE, JSON.stringify(messages, null, 4), function(err) {
        if (err) {
          console.error(err);
          process.exit(1);
        }
        res.json(messages);
      });
    });
  });

  app.listen(PORT, function (err) {
    if (err) {
      return console.log(err);
    }
    console.log('Listening at' + PORT );
  });
}
```

This is webpack-server.js:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var WebpackDevServer = require('webpack-dev-server');
var config = require('./webpack.config');


module.exports = (PORT) => {
  const backendPort = PORT - 1;
  const server = new WebpackDevServer(webpack(config), {
    publicPath: config.output.publicPath,
    hot: true,
    historyApiFallback: true,
    proxy: {
      '*' : {
        target: 'http://localhost:' + backendPort
      }
    }
  });
  server.listen(PORT, 'localhost', function (err) {
    if (err) {
      return console.log(err);
    }
    console.log('Listening at ' + PORT);
  });
}
```

And here is server.js:

```
var apiServer = require('./json-api-server');
var webpackServer = require('./webpack-server');

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4001;
const PROD = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';

if (PROD) {
  apiServer(PORT);
} else {
  apiServer(PORT - 1);
  webpackServer(PORT);
}
```

My filetree looks like:

```
--- /
----- server.js
----- webpack-server.js
----- json-api-server.js
----- src/
------- app/index.js
------- app/data/
-------------- messages.json
```

Both server start correctly and they don't give any errors in the terminal
I can reach localhost:4000/messages
I cannot reach localhost:4001. I got: "Can't get / "

Any helps? :)

Answer (score 0):

Got it!
The `*` symbol here means: Use "*" to proxy all paths to the specified server.

```
proxy: {
      '*' : {
        target: 'http://localhost:' + backendPort
      }
    }
```

Which brings my index to be undefined.

So i have to point the key to the place where my json(or api) lives:

```
proxy: {
          '/messages' : {
            target: 'http://localhost:' + backendPort
          }
        }
```

As reference, this is also a valid solution:

```
proxy: {
 '/messages': 'http://localhost:' + backendPort
}
```